# Reading input GPIO bit on STM32F4

Tags: c, embedded, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I have an STM32F429l-DISC1 board.

I'm trying to read the value on pin PC11. This is the PORTC settings:

```
RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitDef;
GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_11;
GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;
GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOC,&GPIO_InitDef);
```

And this is how i'm pulling the value:

```
uint8_t value =  GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIOC, 11);
```

When I connect the pin to GND i expect to obtain 0 as a value since it's a pullup...
But I'm always getting a 1.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Ask magic libraries author. Who knows what those functions are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIOC, 11);` to `GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_11);` or `GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIOC, 1 << 11);`

DO NOT USE SPL. It is long time DEAD.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much. What is SPL?

Comment: SPL is library you use

Answer (score 0):

you can also refer to this in case [C++ (Cpp) GPIO_ReadInputDataBit Examples](https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/GPIO_ReadInputDataBit/cpp-gpio_readinputdatabit-function-examples.html)